# SSIS throwing Unspecified Error when trying to edit Excel Columns in BIDS

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs without issue in debug mode, but when I try to edit the Excel Source to add more columns it is suddenly throwing the Unspecified Error

```
Error at MMR_MonthlyFiles_Import [Connection manager "Excel"]: SSIS Error Code
DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  
Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".

Error at Add to Temp Table [Excel Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code 
DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection 
method call to the connection manager "Excel" failed with error code 0xC0202009  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the 
AcquireConnection method call failed.

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020801C (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

The path to the excel file opens without issue (I'm using a variable that holds the path and have pasted it into an explorer window and it opened the file).  I have tried editing the Excel source on two other machines (other developers) and they had no issues and did not get the above error.

I was thinking of having the drivers re-installed, but if I click the debug/run button in BIDS it runs without issue so I don't think that will help.  I have also tried rebooting several times and the issue still is not resolved.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting these issues too, you might want  to check the following:

1. ProtectionLevel of the Package (e.g. DontSaveSensitive)
2. Connection string of the Data Source (e.g. Username and passwords)
3. Package Configurations - if you have one and if they are messed
   up..

Hope this helps..